# Почему div находится не там где нужно?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, grid

Сетка с тремя колонками и двумя строками. Между колонками и строками находятся gutter tracks величиной в 10px.
**Вопрос:** почему блок .b отображается в gutter track'е а не в нужной колонке длиной 100px? И как сделать так, чтобы .b был там, где нужно?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [col1-start] 100px [col1-end] 10px [col2-start] 100px [col2-end] 10px [col3-start] 100px [col3-end];
  grid-template-rows: [row1-start] 25px [row1-end] 10px [row2-start] 25px [row2-end];
}

.box {
  background: darkgreen;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.a {
  grid-column: col1-start;
  grid-row: row1-start / row2-end;
}

. b {
  grid-column: col2-start / col2-end;
  grid-row: row1-start;
}

.c {
  grid-column: col2-start;
  grid-row: row2-start;
}

.d {
  grid-column: col3-start;
  grid-row: row1-start / row2-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a"></div>
  <div class="box b"></div>
  <div class="box c"></div>
  <div class="box d"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что дело в опечатке: я написал не .b, а . b, и из-за этого не работало